# sed in linux. lots of parantheses and slashes

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

```
sed -ir 's@getenv\(\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\'\)\.\'dosyam/@getenv\(\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\'\)\.\'/dosya/@g' index.php
```

this command goes to ">" and stays like that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't escape single quotes within a single-quoted string. If you want a string that contains single quotes, put it in double quotes:

```
sed -ir "s@getenv\('DOCUMENT_ROOT'\)\.'dosyam/@getenv\('DOCUMENT_ROOT'\)\.'/dosya/@g" index.php
```

Comment: I thought it will be like PHP regex. Let me try. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `getenv()` function returns a pointer to the value in the environment, or NULL if there is no match.